# Composite Design Pattern Leaf Management

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Most of the descriptions of the composite design pattern I have seen have the `Composite` implement the `add()` and `remove()` methods and leave those methods unimplemented in the `Leaf` objects. For example, the diagram in the [Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) on the subject suggests this, which is more or less the same as the GoF diagram.

Regarding implementing these in the parent `Component` class, the GoF have the following to say:

> Defining the child management interface at the root of the class hierarchy gives you transparency, because you can treat all components uniformly. It costs you safety, however, because clients may try to do meaningless things like add and remove objects from leaves.

I agree that having a `Leaf` implement `remove()` is strange to handle. (Do you delete yourself? Do you have to implement some sort of `NullLeaf` object?) But since the point of the pattern is to make `Leaf`s and `Composite`s behave the same way I don't see why `add()` could be implemented in `Component`.

**My question:** Why can't `Component` at least implement `add()`? Would doing so violate any key design principles? Does doing so no longer make this a composite design pattern? Below is an example in Python which captures the essence of what I tried to implement in my own work:

```
class Component:
    def add(self, other):
        # in Python, may be more natural to define __add__
        c = Composite()
        c.children = self.children + other.children
        return c

class Leaf(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = [self]  # possibly strange?

    def operation(self):
        # operation specific to this leaf

class Composite(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

    def operation(self):
        for child in self.children:
            child.operation()
```

With an "example usage":

```
>>> l1 = Leaf()
>>> l2 = Leaf()
>>> c = l1.add(l2)  # c is a `Composite` instance
>>> c.operation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't Component at least implement add()? Would doing so violate
>   any key design principles? Does doing so no longer make this a
>   composite design pattern?

You answered the question yourself, as you wrote

> Defining the child management interface at the root of the class
>   hierarchy gives you transparency, because you can treat all components
>   uniformly. It costs you safety, however, because clients may try to do
>   meaningless things like add and remove objects from leaves.

It is a trade-off to add the child management methods to the interface. When you do it, you gain the benefit of handling all objects in the hierarchy uniformly. But for the leaves you then have to decide a strategy to deal with interface that makes no sense. What could be done is either create empty implementations for the methods or throw exception when they are called. Yet another way to do it is to create an abstract base class `Component` that defines the `add()` and `remove()` methods, and then just use that implementation in `Composite` and override the methods in `Leaf` with an empty implementation for example. All these implementations are `Composite` pattern variants. IMHO the patterns should not be read word to word but as guiding principles which let you tailor the implementation for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Have you encountered any examples where this kind of variation is implemented? I've seen many where the `Leaf` or `Component` provides empty implementations of `add()` and `remove()` but not ones using a different behavior.